# consulta avanzada Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar una consulta, ya que no me devuelve el resultado deseado.

Me gustaría saber cómo consulto 3 tablas diferentes

[image: Me gustaría saber como consulto 3 tablas diferentes]

Este código, para mí, está bien, pero me falta algo.

```
use heladeria;
select cliente.nombresClientes, facturacion.detalleCompra, tiposhelado.tiposHelado,
from cliente 
join facturacion on cliente.id_Cliente = facturacion.Cliente_id_Cliente
join saborhelado on id_sabores = tiposHelado_idtiposHelado i =
```

Comment: Sólo al mirar la imagen que muestra el diseño de la BD hay deficiencias que repercutirán en las consultas: El id_cliente no es un atributo propio de la tabla tipoHelado. Me parece que te faltan, al menos, dos tablas, una que se refiera a los helados (que incluya su tipo y su sabor, etc.) y otra que detalle la relación entre clientes y helados.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Cuál es el obtenido? Ten en cuenta que este no es un foro de discusión: es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, por lo tanto debes describir el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, tanto en la pregunta misma como en su título. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].

Answer (score 1):

Una consulta que podría funcionar es la siguiente, usando `inner join` y relacionando el **tipoHelado** con la tabla **saboreshelado**.

De todas formas es extraño tener como `foreign key` el cliente en la tabla de tipos de helado. Se nescesitaría una nueva tabla que fuera una tabla de pedidos con la informacion del cliente relacionándola con la de los helados.

```
select cliente.nombresClientes, facturacion.detalleCompra, tiposhelado.tiposHelado, 
from cliente 
inner join facturacion on cliente.id_Cliente = facturacion.Cliente_id_Cliente 
inner join saborhelado on tiposhelado.tiposHelado=saboreshelado.tiposHelado;
```

Comment: Coincido con la idea de una tabla de pedido por ciente. La facturación es más bien un reporte, no una tabla.